# R: Select first occurrence by time date for multiple ID's

Tags: r

For many unique ID's I have multiple events (timestamps) for individual dates - for each ID, I want to pull the row for the first event of each day (earliest time occurrence that day).

Have tried using `dplyr` to group and filter, but haven't been able to just pull out the first (temporally) event for each day for all ID's.

Example Data:

```
    df <- data_frame("DateTime" = c("2018-03-04 16:10:00", "2018-03-04 16:15:00", 
                     "2018-03-04 16:30:00", "2018-03-04 16:40:00", "2018-03-05 16:45:00", 
                     "2018-03-07 16:12:00", "2018-03-07 17:00:00", "2018-03-07 18:12:00"), 
                     "ID" = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this gets you where you want to be:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, lubridate::date(DateTime)) %>%
  arrange(DateTime) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(DateTime, ID)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  DateTime            ID   
  <chr>               <chr>
1 2018-03-04 16:10:00 A    
2 2018-03-04 16:30:00 B    
3 2018-03-05 16:45:00 B    
4 2018-03-07 16:12:00 C
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to format the `DateTime` as a date-time, not a character. `lubridate::ymd_hms` is useful for that (assuming your dates are y-m-d).

Next, convert `DateTime` to a date. Now you can `group_by` ID and date, then `filter` for minimum `DateTime`.

Finally, one way to get time is to format using `strftime`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(DateTime = ymd_hms(DateTime), 
         Date = as_date(DateTime)) %>% 
  group_by(Date, ID) %>% 
  filter(DateTime == min(DateTime)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Time = strftime(DateTime, "%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC"))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  DateTime            ID    Date       Time    
  <dttm>              <chr> <date>     <chr>   
1 2018-03-04 16:10:00 A     2018-03-04 16:10:00
2 2018-03-04 16:30:00 B     2018-03-04 16:30:00
3 2018-03-05 16:45:00 B     2018-03-05 16:45:00
4 2018-03-07 16:12:00 C     2018-03-07 16:12:00
```

Comment: Thanks but that only gets halfway to the answer - your solution will only pull the minimum date/time - I want the min time each day... any ideas there?

Comment: Oh I think I figured it out - split DateTime into separate columns, then add slightly to what you had:          df %>% 
  group_by(ID, Date) %>% 
  filter(Time == min(Time)) %>%
  ungroup()

Comment: Edited. Hope it gets you close to what you need.

Comment: Just a note - if the first event of a day occurs simultaneously with another event, this may result in more than one row per ID per day. While unlikely...it's happened to me before

Comment: I'd argue that where ties occur, it may be better to know about it - _i.e._ retain them and deal with them later.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach but I had a similar problem and I just arranged the dates by ascending order and used distinct(). This seemed to only keep the top entries (in case there is a repeating entry).

In your problem, you want the earliest entry to be kept... So just arranging the data and using distinct should get you your answer.

```
df %>% arrange(ID, date) %>% distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE)
```